# DatePicker flutter change display date format

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How to change format of display date?

[image]

I can't find date format field here. Here is my sample code:

```
_onDateChanging(BuildContext context, DateKind dateKind,
      FlightSearchQueryProvider searchProvider) {
    ...
    showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime.tryParse(date),
      firstDate: DateTime.now(),
      lastDate: DateTime(2050),
      helpText: helperText,
      cancelText: cancelText,
      confirmText: confirmText,
      fieldHintText: hintText,
      errorFormatText: getTranslation(context, 'invalid_date_value'),
      errorInvalidText: getTranslation(context, 'invalid_date_value'),
    ).then((value) {
      if (value != null) {
        if (dateKind == DateKind.Departure) {
          searchProvider.updateDepartureDate(value.toString());
        } else {
          searchProvider.updateArrivalDate(value.toString());
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: You might have to post some code first

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image].
The easiest way that I found is to rewrite `LocalizationsDelegate`

The `showDatePicker` method uses `MaterialLocalizations.of(context);` to format `DatePickerHeader` `dateText` that you need.

To change the format you need to rewrite the `showDatePicker` method or add you own `LocalizationsDelegate`. The second way is much faster.

To add custom `LocalizationsDelegate`:

```
MaterialApp(
 localizationsDelegates: [
   CustomMaterialLocalizationsDelegate(),
  ],
..
)
```

To create `CustomMaterialLocalizationsDelegate` you can copy _MaterialLocalizationsDelegate (link to the delegate you can find in `GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate`)

Next you need to change `mediumDateFormat` variable.

Probably this is not a perfect solution because you change that format for whole MaterialApp, but probably this is the only solution, if you don't want to create you own DatePicker.

Working example:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart' as intl;
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:intl/date_symbols.dart' as intl;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: [
        CustomMaterialLocalizationsDelegate(), // GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: MyHomePage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Test(),
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  const Test({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  _showDialog(BuildContext context) {
    return () => showDatePicker(
          context: context,
          initialDate: DateTime.now(),
          firstDate: DateTime.now(),
          lastDate: DateTime(2050),
        ).then(print);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final localizations = MaterialLocalizations.of(context);
    return Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        child: Text(
            'showDialog: ${localizations.formatMediumDate(DateTime.now())}'),
        onPressed: _showDialog(context),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class CustomMaterialLocalizationsDelegate
    extends LocalizationsDelegate<MaterialLocalizations> {
  const CustomMaterialLocalizationsDelegate();

  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) =>
      kMaterialSupportedLanguages.contains(locale.languageCode);

  static final Map<Locale, Future<MaterialLocalizations>> _loadedTranslations =
      <Locale, Future<MaterialLocalizations>>{};

  @override
  Future<MaterialLocalizations> load(Locale locale) {
    assert(isSupported(locale));
    return _loadedTranslations.putIfAbsent(locale, () {
      // util.loadDateIntlDataIfNotLoaded();

      final String localeName =
          intl.Intl.canonicalizedLocale(locale.toString());
      assert(
        locale.toString() == localeName,
        'Flutter does not support the non-standard locale form $locale (which '
        'might be $localeName',
      );

      intl.DateFormat fullYearFormat;
      intl.DateFormat compactDateFormat;
      intl.DateFormat shortDateFormat;
      intl.DateFormat mediumDateFormat;
      intl.DateFormat longDateFormat;
      intl.DateFormat yearMonthFormat;
      intl.DateFormat shortMonthDayFormat;
      if (intl.DateFormat.localeExists(localeName)) {
        fullYearFormat = intl.DateFormat.y(localeName);
        compactDateFormat = intl.DateFormat.yMd(localeName);
        shortDateFormat = intl.DateFormat.yMMMd(localeName);
        // mediumDateFormat = intl.DateFormat.MMMEd(localeName);
        longDateFormat = intl.DateFormat.yMMMMEEEEd(localeName);
        yearMonthFormat = intl.DateFormat.yMMMM(localeName);
        shortMonthDayFormat = intl.DateFormat.MMMd(localeName);
      } else if (intl.DateFormat.localeExists(locale.languageCode)) {
        fullYearFormat = intl.DateFormat.y(locale.languageCode);
        compactDateFormat = intl.DateFormat.yMd(locale.languageCode);
        shortDateFormat = intl.DateFormat.yMMMd(locale.languageCode);
        // mediumDateFormat = intl.DateFormat.MMMEd(locale.languageCode);
        longDateFormat = intl.DateFormat.yMMMMEEEEd(locale.languageCode);
        yearMonthFormat = intl.DateFormat.yMMMM(locale.languageCode);
        shortMonthDayFormat = intl.DateFormat.MMMd(locale.languageCode);
      } else {
        fullYearFormat = intl.DateFormat.y();
        compactDateFormat = intl.DateFormat.yMd();
        shortDateFormat = intl.DateFormat.yMMMd();
        // mediumDateFormat = intl.DateFormat.MMMEd();
        longDateFormat = intl.DateFormat.yMMMMEEEEd();
        yearMonthFormat = intl.DateFormat.yMMMM();
        shortMonthDayFormat = intl.DateFormat.MMMd();
      }

      mediumDateFormat = intl.DateFormat.y(); // <- added

      intl.NumberFormat decimalFormat;
      intl.NumberFormat twoDigitZeroPaddedFormat;
      if (intl.NumberFormat.localeExists(localeName)) {
        decimalFormat = intl.NumberFormat.decimalPattern(localeName);
        twoDigitZeroPaddedFormat = intl.NumberFormat('00', localeName);
      } else if (intl.NumberFormat.localeExists(locale.languageCode)) {
        decimalFormat = intl.NumberFormat.decimalPattern(locale.languageCode);
        twoDigitZeroPaddedFormat = intl.NumberFormat('00', locale.languageCode);
      } else {
        decimalFormat = intl.NumberFormat.decimalPattern();
        twoDigitZeroPaddedFormat = intl.NumberFormat('00');
      }

      return SynchronousFuture<MaterialLocalizations>(getMaterialTranslation(
        locale,
        fullYearFormat,
        compactDateFormat,
        shortDateFormat,
        mediumDateFormat,
        longDateFormat,
        yearMonthFormat,
        shortMonthDayFormat,
        decimalFormat,
        twoDigitZeroPaddedFormat,
      ));
    });
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReload(CustomMaterialLocalizationsDelegate old) => false;

  @override
  String toString() =>
      'GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate(${kMaterialSupportedLanguages.length} locales)';
}
```

**Updated**.
I've noticed that you are from Türkmenistan.
Maybe you what to change the `Local`, the dialog has this option from the box.

But unfortunately I didn't fund Turkmen, this is Russian.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: [
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: MyHomePage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Test(),
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  const Test({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  _showDialog(BuildContext context) {
    return () => showDatePicker(
          locale: Locale('ru', 'ru_Ru'),
          context: context,
          initialDate: DateTime.now(),
          firstDate: DateTime.now(),
          lastDate: DateTime(2050),
        ).then(print);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        child: Text('showDialog'),
        onPressed: _showDialog(context),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!)) Solution is good, but very difficult to use it in practice, I already have a custom Turkmen language(MaterialLocalizationTkDelegate) and this is not the best way to change the date of  DatePicker, because I used DefaultMaterialLocalizations(reason is that I don't want rewrite all of MaterialLocalizations fields, they are too many!). Unfortunately, flutter doesn't provide date customization from the box, I'll search for another solution.

Comment: The problem of this answer is that it changes locale if that language exists in localization list here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_localizations/GlobalMaterialLocalizations-class.html And unfortunately turkmen language is not added here. So how can i programmatically customize it for that language?

Comment: Hi @Ruslanbek0809, I've already created support for Turkmen language.  Place, where I found solution is: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization#adding-support-for-a-new-language, you'll find link to github in that topic "add_language".

Comment: @AtamyratBabayev Thanx man.

Comment: @Ruslanbek0809 Hi, I created file for support turkmen language, you could find it here: https://github.com/Mickey-A-Mouse/turkmen_localization_flutter